# belongsTo - hasMany - getting instance from belongsTo - sequelize

Tags: associations, sequelize.js

Provided I have following models:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var WorkingCalendar = sequelize.define('WorkingCalendar', {
    date: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    isWorking: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
  }, {
      indexes: [{
        unique: true,
        fields: ['PeriodId', 'date']
      }]
    }, {
      classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
          WorkingCalendar.belongsTo(models.Period);
        }
      }
    });
  return WorkingCalendar;
};

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Period = sequelize.define('Period', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    numberOfPeriods: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Period.hasMany(models.WorkingCalendar);
      }
    }
  });
  return Period;
};
```

And then trying to get the `Period` through the `WorkingCalendar` as follows:

```
return models.WorkingCalendar
.findAll({
    attributes: [
        'PeriodId',
        'date'
    ],
    include: [
        { model: models.Period }
    ],
    group: ['date', 'PeriodId']
});
```

I'm getting following error: **Unhandled rejection Error: Period is not associated to WorkingCalendar!**

Yet it does work the other way around.

My question:
Why can't I get the `Period` through the `WorkingCalendar`? And what do I have to do to make sure I can?

I have already tried putting the `foreignKey` attribute on the association as wel as the `as` binding but to no avail sadly. Any help would be very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally found it.
The `indexes` should be in the same object as `classMethods`

**WRONG**

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
 var WorkingCalendar = sequelize.define('WorkingCalendar', {
    date: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    isWorking: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
  }, {
      indexes: [{
        unique: true,
        fields: ['PeriodId', 'date']
      }]
    }, {
      classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
          WorkingCalendar.belongsTo(models.Period);
        }
      }
    });
  return WorkingCalendar;
};
```

**RIGHT**

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var WorkingCalendar = sequelize.define('WorkingCalendar', {
    date: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    isWorking: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
  }, {
      indexes: [{
        unique: true,
        fields: ['PeriodId', 'date']
      }],
      classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
          WorkingCalendar.belongsTo(models.Period);
        }
      }
    });
  return WorkingCalendar;
};
```